# Py4JJavaError decision tree presiction using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, decision-tree

I'm trying to applicate a decision tree model on a data set using pyspark
the dataset:https://www.kaggle.com/c/customer-churn-prediction-2020/data?select=test.csv
the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZJLGHaXMQwa-nsjieUTvK0kX_ZPqUpWH/view?usp=sharing

i have an error in the line `model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=2,categoricalFeaturesInfo={1:2, 3:4, 4:2, 5:2},impurity='gini', maxDepth=5, maxBins=32)`

the error is : [image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
can anyone explained to we where is the problem and how can I fix it
PS: I used the same code in another data set in another problem and it worked perfectly

Comment: Could you post the complete traceback? It is truncated in your picture.